# Get struct from function

Tags: c, struct

I'm looking to return a struct with multidimensional data from a function. The idea: gather struct info in function, then assign *dummy struct* to struct `patches`, then use `patches` information in a different function and loop over it.

This is what I have. How can I do this properly?

```
struct patchdata {
    char* version;
    char* size;
    char* compatible;
};

int ourfunction(struct patchdata* patches) {
    size_t count = 12;

    struct patchdata tmp[count];

    tmp[0] = "Version 1.0";
    tmp[1] = "Version 2.0";
    tmp[2] = "Version 3.0";

    if (patches) {
        memcpy(patches, &tmp, sizeof(*patches));
    }
}

struct patchdata patchstruct;

int main()
{
    ourfunction(&patchstruct);

    printf("Test: %s\n", patchstruct[0].version);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what do you expect `sizeof(*patches)` returns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simpler way is to assign struct fields expicitly:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

struct patchdata {
    char *version;
    char *size;
    char *compatible;
};

int ourfunction(struct patchdata *patches) {
    if (patches) {
        // assuming patches points to an array of at least 3 structures

        patches[0].version = "Version 1.0";
        patches[0].size = NULL;
        patches[0].compatible = NULL;

        patches[1].version = "Version 2.0";
        patches[1].size = NULL;
        patches[1].compatible = NULL;

        patches[2].version = "Version 3.0";
        patches[2].size = NULL;
        patches[2].compatible = NULL;
        return 0;
    } else {
        return -1;
    }
}

int main() {
    struct patchdata patchstruct[3];

    ourfunction(patchstruct);

    printf("Test: %s\n", patchstruct[0].version);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to keep `patchstruct` as a global without size?

Comment: @AppelFlap: no, arrays have a fixed size in C. Either define `patchstruct` local in `main` with a possibly parametric size, or global with a compile time constant size, or define a pointer and allocate and reallocate the structure array as needed.